# Is there a way to print a PDF but setting the values maunally and not taking them from the main HTML?

Tags: javascript, pdf, extjs, pdf-generation

I need to add a "Print PDF" option to my site, but my problem is that I use Ext.js, so the code of my site is not in HTML. I have been searching about how to print a pdf from the website and I only find how to do it throught HTML. So I wonder if there is any library or something to set what I want to print manually instead of taking it from the HTML code.

That's how I define the table I want to print out in a PDF file

```
const store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                storeId:'hotelsStore',
                fields:['name', 'Best price', 'Price1', 'Price2', 'Price3'],
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'items'
                    }
                }
            });

            const grid = Ext.define('KitchenSink.view.grid.CellEditing', {
                extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',                
                xtype: 'cell-editing',
                initComponent: function() {                   
                    Ext.apply(this, {
                        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('hotelsStore'),
                        columns: [
                        {
                            header: 'Name',
                            dataIndex: 'name',
                            width: 300                           
                        }, {
                            header: 'Best price',
                            dataIndex: 'bestPrice',
                            width: 105
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'Price1',
                            dataIndex: 'priceSite1',
                            width: 200
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'Price2',
                            dataIndex: 'priceSite2',
                            width: 200
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'Price3',
                            dataIndex: 'priceSite3',
                            width: 200
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                            width: 30,
                            sortable: false,
                            menuDisabled: true,
                            id: 'delete-column',
                            items: [{
                                icon: '/assets/img/delete.png',
                                tooltip: 'Delete',
                                scope: this,
                                handler: this.onRemoveClick
                            }],

                        }],
                        dockedItems: [{
                            xtype: 'toolbar',
                            items: [{
                                text: 'Add',
                                scope: this,
                                handler: this.add
                            }, {
                                text: 'Print values',
                                scope: this,
                                hander: this.printValues
                            }, {
                                text: 'Logout',
                                scope: this,
                                handler: this.logout
                            }]
                        }],                     
                    });

                    this.callParent();
},
```

The values I want to print in a PDF are in this array:

```
function fillData()
  for(var i = 0; i<hotelNames.length; i++) {
      dataArray.push({ 'name': names[i], 'bestPrice': results[i2], 'Price1': 
      results[i4], 'Price2': results[i5], 'Price3': results[i6]})
      i2 = i2 + 4;
      i3 = i3 + 4;
      i4 = i4 + 4;
      i5 = i5 + 4;
      i6 = i6 + 4;
  }
}
```

And finally, that's how I fill the table

```
fillData();
store.getProxy().data = dataArray;
store.load();
```

As you can see, I do not have any HTML code. Ext.js uses JavaScript, so how would I achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PDFMake](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/) or [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html)  libraries.

**PDFMake** (PDF document generation library for server-side and client-side usage in pure JavaScript.).

**PDFKit** (PDFKit is a PDF document generation library for Node and the browser that makes creating complex, multi-page, printable documents easy. The API embraces chainability, and includes both low level functions as well as abstractions for higher level functionality. The PDFKit API is designed to be simple, so generating complex documents is often as simple as a few function calls.)

---

**Updated! How to use PDFKit in Browser?**

To Use PDFKit inside your browser first you should add [blobStream JS](https://github.com/devongovett/blob-stream/releases/download/v0.1.3/blob-stream.js) than [PDFkit JS](https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/releases/download/v0.8.0/pdfkit.js)

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- blobStream JS -->
    <script src="lib/blob-stream.js"></script>
    <!-- PDFKit JS -->
    <script src="lib/pdfkit.js"></script>

    <!-- Other Scripts -->

    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="printDoc" > Print Something </a>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var element = document.getElementById('printDoc'); 
element.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
 // create a document and pipe to a blob
        var doc = new PDFDocument();
        var stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());

        // draw some text
        doc.fontSize(25).text('Stackoverflow with smile :) ', 100, 80);

        doc.end();
        stream.on('finish', function () {

               window.open(stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf'), '_blank');
        });

});
```

[Demo](http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html)

Comment: I am going to pick PDFKit. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I have just tried PDFKit and it seems to be generating the PDF correctly, however I would like to show it in the browser instead of saving it locally since my site is hosted in a server. So I tried the Browser Usage and when I run it I get this error: ```this._blob = new Blob(this.chunks, {``` ```Blob is not a constructor```. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure but if you wanna have preview before saving it you should check here [PDFKit Browser Demo](https://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html) and you should know  blobStream is for the browser is not work in server-side.

Comment: Alright, I will take a look at it. Thank you :) 

I know blobStream is for the client-side, but how would I use it since it needs a ```require``` and that is for Node.js? It is not possible to do a ```require``` in the client-side... I do not get it.

Comment: You're welcome, for sure require is not work and you don't need to use require in the client-side, use it like the "PDFKit Browser Demo Example" : 
`var doc = new PDFDocument();`
`var stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());` ....

Comment: Alright, I have looked better at its documentation and apparently I need to use ```browserify``` in order to preview the pdf in a web browser. However, it was a bit confusing at first since the example previews it in an ```iframe``` and I do not have that on my website, so I had to look at the browserify documentation and I needed to use ```const url = stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf');``` ```window.open(url);``` instead of ```iframe.src = stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf');```. I explain this so it might be helpful for someone.